# Did the "bonus" Piccolo get in Dragon Ball Super: Super Hero come from his dormant power or not?

Tags: dragon-ball-super, dragon-ball-movies

In Dragon Ball Super: Super Hero,

> Piccolo achieved both his Potential Unleashed form as well as this higher level form (Orange Piccolo) thanks to a wish from Shenron to unlock his potential, who grants him the latter as a bonus boost in strength. [Orange Piccolo](https://dragonball.fandom.com/wiki/Orange_Piccolo)

Did the "bonus" Piccolo get in Dragon Ball Super: Super Hero come from his dormant power or not?